# JSON.parse issue with single quotation

Tags: javascript

I have below JSON string

```
var value = "{'type':'youtube','id':'https://www.youtube.com/embed/JlLGdc71LUc','title':'<strong>mental</strong> <strong>health</strong> & it's benifits for testqaabhi','playerId':'','playerKey':''}";
```

If I use `JSON.parse(value);` than it give me error. I just wanted to replace  single quote with double quote except that in `it's` string . Can anybody suggest any method. I had another solution using regular expression to replace it. But I'm calling replace method again and again. So If anybody can minimize it.

```
value.replace(/^{'/,'{"').replace(/'}$/,'"}').replace(/':'/g,'":"').replace(/','/g,'","')
```

*JSON string is incorrect and coming from other source on which I don't have control. So can't update JSON string.*

Comment: Can't you fix the string generator? Why do you have such string?

Comment: first do one thing, validate your JSON in jsonlint.com. Once its a valid JSON, then you can move ahead, otherwise try to work on JSON string to get with correct format

Comment: Unless this is coming to you from an external source, I would first fix the JSON as @AnandharamanBuvaneswaran suggested above. Everything should work out of the box afterwards.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON string. All the field names need to have double quotes in a valid JSON

Comment: It's not a valid  JSON and  title  should  be escaped  before  creating  JSON object.

Comment: JSON string is coming from other sources on which I don't have control. So can't update JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

value is an object. (creating from an object literal)

JSON.parse() is used to convert a string containing JSON notation into a Javascript object.

Your code turns the object into a string (by calling .toString()) in order to try to parse it as JSON text.
The default .toString() returns "[object Object]", which is not valid JSON; hence the error.

use JSON.stringify() function for convert your JS object to JSON object... after that you can call JSON.parse() for your JSON object

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse(value.replace(/'/g,"\"").replace(/"s/g,"'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"type": "youtube",
"id": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JlLGdc71LUc",
"title": "<strong>mental</strong> <strong>health</strong> & its benifits for testqaabhi",
"playerId": "",
"playerKey": ""
}
```

I would be a valid JSON. Your JSON failed because you have used quote(') on the title.

use this

its benifits for testqaabhi

instead of

it's benifits for testqaabhi

Comment: I know that but JSON data is coming from other source on which I don't have control. So can't update JSON string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this.

```
var xx="{'type':'youtube','id':'https://www.youtube.com/embed/JlLGdc71LUc','title':'<strong>mental</strong> <strong>health</strong> & it's benifits for testqaabhi','playerId':'','playerKey':''}";

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(xx));
```